# force new window (AppleScript/keyboard) even though `open folders in tab` is selected?

Tags: finder

i looking for a way to create a shortcut that will force finder to create a new window (via AppleScript/keyboard) even though `open folders in tab` is selected. I cant for the life of me get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it just not technically possible?

Comment: I am also very interested in the solution to this problem. Some software is just not meant to be opened in tabs, but I want to keep the tab behaviour of other apps like Finder. +1